# Length of a Lipschitz function

Tags: analysis, curves, lipschitz-functions

We have the following well know definition:

> If  $\gamma: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is an injective and continuously differentiable function, then the length of  $\gamma$ is defined as the quantity
> $$\operatorname{Length}(\gamma) ~ \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} ~ \int_{a}^{b} |\gamma'(t)| ~ \mathrm{d}{t}.$$

If I now take a Lipschitz curve $c:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$, then we have by Rademacher theorem $\gamma$ is differentiable almost everywhere with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Do we have in this case too, that
$$\operatorname{Length}(c) =  \int_{a}^{b} |c'(t)| ~ \mathrm{d}{t}?$$
Many thanks for some help!

Comment: Yes, this is true.  In general for a not-necessarily-smooth curve $\gamma$ one defines length as a limit of $\sum_i|\gamma(a_{i+1})-\gamma(a_{i})|$ where the limit is taken over finer and finer partitions $a_1<a_2\dots$ of the domain.  If $\gamma$ is Lipschitz (or just absolutely continuous) then your formula will be true, as a theorem, rather than a definition.  Moreover, if $\gamma$ has finite length, then it will always have a Lipschitz reparametrization (the arc-length parametrization).  Don't have time right now to write up or link a rigorous proof so I'll leave this as a comment for now.